# Difference of two summaries results null

Tags: devexpress, report

I want to get result as difference of two sums of column in report.
using following formula in result label show me nothing when column IssuedQty is null

```
sumSum([IssuedQty])-sumSum([RecieveQty])
```

[This is the report display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK785.png)

How can i get result weather in negitive value or positive value without getting nothing in label text.

Comment: Please try separate summaries by [IssuedQty] and by [RecieveQty] fields. may be it will show us some details and specifics.

Also if you want to skip the Null values, you may check the "Ignore null values" in option the [Summary Editor][1] form.


  [1]: https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/119436/Detailed-Guide-to-DevExpress-Reporting/Shape-Report-Data/Shape-Data-Expression-Bindings/Calculate-a-Summary

Answer (score 0):

You may use logical functions like 'Iif(condition, true, false)' and check if the [IssuedQty] column has null value. I don't know if this functions work in the report but it can be written like this:

Sum( Iif([IssuedQty] is null, 0, [IssuedQty]) ) - Sum([RecieveQty])
You will check that if column is null then it will return true part which is 0, otherwise it will return its value.

There are other logical functions you may use like 'IsNull()' [here the reference](https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/4928/DevExpress-Data-Library/Criteria-Language-Syntax).